# Selenium WebDriver and Java permgen space error

Tags: java, selenium

I have a test suite of 50 tests and after running some 30 tests, my build fails by giving a java.lang.OutOfMemory : permgen space. I have searched online and tried to increase the permgen space, changed the JAVA_OPTS, MAVEN_OPTS also.But none of this seem to work.The tests still fail. Now either I have not set the space correctly or I am not approaching the problem in the right way. my application is using Grails with selenium webdriver 2.19.

Please help.

Comment: How did you adjust the pergen space, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m?

Comment: I did export JAVA_OPTS specifying the permgen space

Comment: But did you try using Peter's solution exactly? JAVA_OPTS may not be read...

Comment: if there is a possibility that the JAVA_OPTS may not be read, then how can I make sure that it will read the parameters that i have given?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find and fix the class loader leak.

Find Informations here: https://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java

Answer (score 0):

How much memory did you specify? Probably that was not enough. Try to run $JAVA_HOME/bin/jvisualvm after your application/test cases are started and to find out how much does it really need.